# Proof-theoretic ordinals: inevitable consistency?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, proof-theory, reverse-math

There are various different notions of the proof-theoretic ordinal of a theory; most of these are "notation-dependent" in that they're only nontrivial once we restrict attention to a class of "natural" notations. There are, however, ways to attack this in a notation-independent way (e.g. the supremum of the ordinals which have notations which the theory proves induction along).

I'm interested in the following naive variant on the (notation-dependent) definition "The least ordinal such that induction along that ordinal proves the consistency of the theory:"

*By "notation" below I mean "element of [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O)," but if some other notion of notation would be preferable feel free to use it instead - **if** (1) it is precisely defined (= no reference to "naturality" etc. and (2) every computable ordinal has at least one notation (= no cheating by only going up partway).*

---

Suppose $T$ is an "appropriate" theory - that is, recursively axiomatizable, fully sound, interpreting PA, and (for simplicity) in the language of second-order arithmetic (so we can talk directly about well-foundedness).

> The **inevitable consistency ordinal** of $T$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that for **every** notation $n$ for $\alpha$, RCA$_0$ + "The ordering defined by $n$ is well-founded" proves the consistency of $T$.

A couple comments:

- Per the second section of [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/333516/8133), if we replace "every" by "some" we always get $\omega$; the point of inevitability is that there's no way to **avoid** getting consistency, no matter how we describe $\alpha$ to RCA$_0$ we wind up getting Con$(T)$.)*
- I'm replacing the usual base theory PRA with the stronger theory RCA$_0$ so I don't have to worry about low-level shenanigans; I'm really not interested in optimal calculations right now, just coarse behavior.

---

While inevitable consistency is a fully notation-independent notation, it's not clear to me that the corresponding ordinal always exists - to put it mildly!

My question is:

> Does the inevitable consistency ordinal of ACA$_0$ (which is conservative over PA) exist?

If the answer is "yes," natural follow-up questions include:

- Is it equal to $\epsilon_0$ (or at least close to that)?
- Does such an ordinal *always* exist for an appropriate $T$?

  - Note that the ordinal described in the parenthetical of the first paragraph of this question does in fact always exist, by $\Sigma^1_1$ bounding, so this isn't as ridiculous as it may sound.

One unconditional further question which occurs to me is:

- How "coarse" can inevitable consistency be - e.g. is there an obvious reason why, if the inevitable consistency ordinal for $\Pi^1_1$-CA$_0$ (say) exists, then it must be different from that of ACA$_0$?

Comment: The computability-theory and reverse-mathematics tags are speculative, but in my opinion justified - I think there's a good chance that, although this question isn't specifically about either topic, *techniques* from those topics may be relevant here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ineventable consistency ordinals do not exist for all the computably axiomatizable extensions of $\mathsf{RCA}_0$. Indeed, for any given notation system $\alpha$ I'll construct a notation system $\alpha^*$ such that $\alpha$ and $\alpha^*$ are notations for the same ordinal and $\mathsf{RCA_0}\vdash \lnot \mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{RCA}_0)\to\mathsf{WF}(\alpha^*)$. By Gödel's second incompleteness theorem the theory $\mathsf{RCA}_0+\lnot\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{RCA}_0)$ is consistent. And hence we would have consistency of $\mathsf{RCA_0}+\lnot\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{RCA}_0)+\mathsf{WF}(\alpha^*)$. Which of course mean that $\mathsf{RCA}_0+\mathsf{WF}(\alpha^*)$ doesn't prove $\mathsf{Con}(T)$, for any computably axiomatizable extension $T$ of $\mathsf{RCA}_0$.

Now I'll construct $\alpha^*$. Let us work in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$. For each $n$ we consider the finite binary relation $\alpha\upharpoonright_n$ that consists of all $\beta<n$ such that the witness for the $\Sigma_1$ sentence $\beta<_{\mathcal{O}^*}\alpha$ is less than $n$ and $\beta_1<_{\alpha\upharpoonright_n} \beta_2$ if the witness for the $\Sigma_1$ sentence $\beta_1<_{\mathcal{O}^*}\beta_2$ is less than $n$. Let $\alpha^*_n$ to be $\alpha\upharpoonright_m$, where $m$ is the greatest number $\le n$ such that there are no proofs of contradiction in $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ of the length $<m$ and the binary relation $\alpha\upharpoonright_m$ is well-founded. Clearly, $\alpha^*_n$ constitute uniformly computable sequence of binary relations such that $\alpha^*_n\subseteq \alpha^*_{n'}$, for $n\le n'$. We define $\alpha^*$ to be an element of $\mathcal{O}^*$ such that the cone below it is isomorphic to $\bigcup_{n\in \omega} \alpha^*_n$ and each $\beta<_{\mathcal{O}^*}\alpha^{\star}$ is successor iff it was successor in $\alpha$. Observe that from the assumptions that $\mathsf{RCA}_0$ is consistent and that $\alpha$ is well-founded it follows that $\alpha\upharpoonright_ n=\alpha^*_n$, for all $n$ and hence that $\alpha^*$ is isomorphic to $\alpha$ and is an element of $\mathcal{O}$. On the other hand from the assumption that $\lnot\mathsf{Con}(\mathsf{RCA}_0)$ we conclude that $\alpha^*$ is some $\alpha^*_n$ and hence is a finite well-founded order.

Note that this ineventable ordinals wouldn't exist even if we would define it as

> the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that for every notation $n$ for $\alpha$, $\mathsf{RCA}_0+\text{full scheme of transfinite induction over the order defined by $n$}$ proves the consistency of T.

This was proved by Beklemeishev [[1]](https://www.mi-ras.ru/%7Ebekl/Papers/ex2.ps). The argument above essentially is based on similar ideas, but for a simpler case.

[1] Beklemishev, L.D. (2000): Another pathological well-ordering. In S. Buss et al., editors, Logic Colloquium '98 Proceedings, Lecture Notes in Logic 13, A.K.Peters, Ltd., Natick MA, 105-108.

Comment: Thanks for the added detail - this is great!

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know of any other notation-independent definitions of proof-theoretic ordinals other than the sup of the ordertypes of primitive recursive relations the theory proves are well-founded? I remember hearing of such, but now that I think about it I can't recall any details.

Comment: In the initial answer I claimed that my argument is essentially identical to the argument of Beklemishev, which isn't correct since Beklemishev actually proved stronger result. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @NoahSchweber The notation-independent definitions that I am aware of are equivalent to the standard suprema of the order types of well-founded relations (at least for strong enough systems). I note couple that have a flavour that is a bit different from the standard one. People have considered the supremas of order types of all notation systems $\alpha$ with fixed systems of fundamental seuqneces such that given system $T$ proves that in any infinite set there is an $\alpha$-large finite subset.

Comment: Since that one requires a fixed system of fundamental sequences I think I still consider it notation-dependent. But it's definitely interesting!

Comment: @NoahSchweber And there is a definition recently proposed by James Walsh and me ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.02095 ). Namely, one could consider the order on computably axiomatizable extensions $T$ of $\mathsf{ACA}_0$: $T_1<_{\Pi^1_1\text{-}RFN}T_2$ iff $T_2$ proves that $T_1$ is $\Pi^1_1$-sound. It happen that all $\Pi^1_1$-sound theories lie in the well-founded part of this order. Thus we have well-founded ranks for elements of this order. The correspondence with the standard proof-theoretic ordinals is that the theory with rank $\alpha$ have the proof-theoretic ordinal $\varepsilon_\alpha$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber You don't need to have fixed system of fundamental sequences. You just quantify over all compuable objects that constitute a pair of a linear order and system of fundamental sequences for it.